# Parse YouTube JSON for UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, youtube

I am trying to have a UITableView that displays the title, thumbnail, viewcount, and duration of some youtube videos on a specific channel. The link is this

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=remedyLIVE&max-results=5&v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=published

And the JSON looks like this

```
{
    apiVersion = "2.1";
    data =     {
        items =         (
                        {
                accessControl =                 {
                    autoPlay = allowed;
                    comment = allowed;
                    commentVote = allowed;
                    embed = allowed;
                    list = allowed;
                    rate = allowed;
                    syndicate = allowed;
                    videoRespond = moderated;
                };
                aspectRatio = widescreen;
                category = Music;
                commentCount = 0;
                content =                 {
                    1 = "rtsp://r3---sn-jc47eu7l.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQkbMrdTdbNpexMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp";
                    5 = "https://www.youtube.com/v/e2mzdVO3Mhs?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata";
                    6 = "rtsp://r3---sn-jc47eu7l.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQkbMrdTdbNpexMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp";
                };
                description = "In this episode of IchthusTV My Epic talks about seeking help within the church. -- Text 'Remedy' to 313131 if you need to chat. RemedyLIVE: We Chat, Listen, and Love www.remedyLIVE.com.";
                duration = 109;
                id = e2mzdVO3Mhs;
                player =                 {
                    default = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2mzdVO3Mhs&feature=youtube_gdata_player";
                    mobile = "https://m.youtube.com/details?v=e2mzdVO3Mhs";
                };
                thumbnail =                 {
                    hqDefault = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e2mzdVO3Mhs/hqdefault.jpg";
                    sqDefault = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e2mzdVO3Mhs/default.jpg";
                };
                title = "My Epic - Help within the Church";
                updated = "2014-11-11T20:00:03.000Z";
                uploaded = "2014-11-11T20:00:03.000Z";
                uploader = chatlistenlove;
            },
                        {
                accessControl =                 {
                    autoPlay = allowed;
                    comment = allowed;
                    commentVote = allowed;
                    embed = allowed;
                    list = allowed;
                    rate = allowed;
                    syndicate = allowed;
                    videoRespond = moderated;
                };
                aspectRatio = widescreen;
                category = People;
                commentCount = 0;
                content =                 {
```

etc... I won't post the whole thing but you can see it on the link above! As this is my first time working with JSON I understand that I need to parse this to an array or dictionary but I am just a bit confused on what exactly the "objectforkey" methods look like once I have the data. None of the tutorials I see apply to what I am doing so specific help would be awesome! Here is my code so far

```
[super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell"
                                               bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell"];



    NSURL *youtubeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=remedyLIVE&max-results=5&v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=published"];


    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:youtubeURL];
        if (data == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"data is nil");
        }
        else
        {
            NSError *error;
            titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            videoIDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            thumbArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSLog(@"%@", json);


            for (NSDictionary *item in json)
            {
                NSDictionary* snippet = [item objectForKey:@"snippet"];
                title = [snippet objectForKey:@"title"];
                videoID = [[snippet objectForKey:@"resourceId"] objectForKey:@"videoId"];
                thumbURL = [[[snippet objectForKey:@"thumbnails"] objectForKey:@"default"] objectForKey:@"url"];


                [titleArray addObject:title];
                [videoIDArray addObject:videoID];
                [thumbArray addObject:thumbURL];
            }

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
```

For example why is the word "snippet" chosen? I found this on another stack overflow post about this but I don't understand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `NSArray *json` is wrong on two counts. First the top element is a dictionary. Second the name is bad, it is not JSON so name it for what it is, ex: `videoDictionary`. JSON is what you got from the `dataWithContentsOfURL:` call.

Comment: Okay that makes sense! Thanks, so I'm confused about how the top element is not a video, how would I deal with it? @Zaph

Comment: You are going to have to study the [JSON](http://www.json.org) to determine the structure. Then you can plan how to obtain the information you need. See: [JSON](http://www.json.org) Pasting the JSON into an editor (or web site) that understands JSON should highlight the structure and help you understand it.

Comment: @Zaph Okay, thank you I have been researching it for a couple hours now I'm just having trouble moving these general ideas about JSON into actual Obj-C code...

Comment: One of the things that will help you is that you don't *have* to use `objectForKey` anymore. You can use shorthand notation like: `aDictionary[@"key"][0][@"anotherKey"]` so long as you check that the properties are valid (or wrap it in a try/catch block).

Comment: Okay awesome! That will make it easier, and It turns out the dictionary is returning two keys one for the api with the value 2.1 and one for the data which is EVERYTHING else. How can I parse the "data" also? @remus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can parse NSDictionary objects (translated by parsing JSON objects) using short hand notation. To get to the value you want, use something like this:

```
NSURL* playbackUrl = [NSURL urlWithString:yourDictionary[@"data"][@"items"][@"player"]["mobile"]];
```

To prevent crashes when the property doesn't exist, you'll want to use a try catch block:

```
@try {
        NSURL* playbackUrl = [NSURL urlWithString:yourDictionary[@"data"][@"items"][@"player"]["mobile"]];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
     // handle exception
}
```